# express.static() unable to send static files

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Can anyone help why this piece of code is not working...I also tried this:

```
app.use("/static",express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

but it didn't work. And it's not like that I don't have the "public" folder or anything.

Image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcG2q.png

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the file structure? (Show where your server file is & public folder)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcG2q.png

Comment: when using this middleware, you need to provide the path same as the public folder, for example if you want respond to browser the untitled2 image, the URL must be `http://localhost:3000/static/images/untitled2.png`

Comment: Yeah, I used  ```app.use("/static",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public"))); ``` for that

Answer (score 0):

we can use this code `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`
instead of this`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`